# Problems with BigQuery and Cloud SQL in same project

Tags: google-bigquery

So, we have this one project which uses Cloud Storage and BigQuery as services. All has been well.

Then, I wanted to add Cloud SQL to this project to try it out. It asked for a unique Project ID so I gave it one. (The Project ID is different than the Project Number.)

Ever since then, I've been having a difficult time accessing my BigQuery tables. When I go to the BigQuery web interface, the URL contains the Project ID instead of the original Project Number. It shows the list of datasets, but now shows the Project Number before each dataset name and the datasets are greyed out and inaccessible. If I manually change the URL to contain the Project Number instead of the Project ID, it appears to work although it shows the list of datasets in the left nav twice, one set greyed out and inaccessible and the other set seemingly accessible.

At the same time, some code that I've been successfully using in Apps Script that accesses BigQuery is now regularly failing with a generic "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." I'm not sure if this is related to the Project ID/Project Number confusion, or if it's just a Red Herring.

Since we actively use the Cloud Storage service of this project, I am trying to be cautious with further experimentation with this project. I'm not sure if I should delete the Cloud SQL service in this project to get it back to the way it was, or if this is a known issue with some back-end solution. Please advise.

Comment: While trying to solve the Google Apps Script problem with accessing BigQuery, I tried creating another script with exactly the same code that used to work before. This time, when authorizing the code (to gain access to the BigQuery API), it gave this error:

"The script has been denied access to your data. To allow access, re-run the script and grant access."

Not sure why it's denied considering I'm using the account that is one of the owners of the project. I tried updating the code to reference the new Project ID instead of the Project Number, but this didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the project id, there can be a delay where BigQuery picks up the change. It should happen within 15 minutes or so, but sometimes it takes longer.
If you send the project ID I can make sure it has been updated.